# Natural Breaks - Slice vs Reclassify in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, reclassify

I'm wondering what is the difference between Reclassify tool and Slice tool while using Natural Breaks method.

Below some output from **Reclassify** tool - 5 class; Natural Breaks (Jenks) method:

[image]

Here output from **Slice** tool - Slice Method: Natural Breaks, 5 zones

[image]

[image]

Those two raster are very similar but they're not the same. Maybe You can see it better here:

[image]

I'll be very glad if anyone could tell me why those two raster are not the same. They both using Natural Breaks method.

Maybe **Slice** using different algorithm than Jenks?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the two tools, while similar, use different algorithms.  They are both used for reclassifying data, but they work slightly differently.  Looking at the [Overview of the Reclass toolset](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/an-overview-of-the-reclass-tools.htm), the Reclass tool is used for reclassifying individual values.  However, the Slice tool is used for reclassifying a range of values.

This is somewhat confusing, but the example used in the [Slice concept page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/grouping-values-into-intervals-or-by-area-with-slice.htm) might clear it up.  Also, the [slice documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/slice.htm) states that:

> Slice works best on data that is normally distributed. When using
>   input raster data that is skewed, the output result may not contain
>   all of the classes that you had expected or specified.

I also found [Why is quantile reclassification method yielding classes of vastly different cell counts?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/109183/7424) which indicates that converting the raster to integer may give better results.